# Kubernetes deployment failing due to Image pull failure

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

While trying to deploy my custom nginx image from local registry to kubernetes , I am seeing below error in kubernetes-dashboard -

Failed to pull image "myapp": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: repository myapp not found: does not exist or no pull access

This is the steps I followed -

```
1) Built my customer image using docker
2) kubectl run myapp --image=myapp --port=80 --image-pull-policy=IfNotPresent
3) kubectl expose deployment myapp --type=LoadBalancer --port=80 --target-port=80 --name=myapp
```

In Kubernetes-dashboard, I see deployment showing failure due to above error of repository myapp not found.

I even tried to add this steps mentioned in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

```
docker login
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=https://index.docker.io/v1/ --docker-username=xxx --docker-password=xxx --docker-email=xxx
```

But still same issue.

What should I do for pod to get my local repo in GKE.
Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Here is the more info as requested by rjdkolb -

```
xxx@cloudshell:~ (involuted-ratio-227118)$ kubectl describe pod myapp-7cf96cf48-vsqb5
Name:           myapp-7cf96cf48-vsqb5
Namespace:      default
Node:           gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-c7d671ed-br8j/10.142.0.3
Start Time:     Wed, 09 Jan 2019 22:28:58 +0530
Labels:         pod-template-hash=379527904
                run=myapp
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/limit-ranger=LimitRanger plugin set: cpu request for container myapp
Status:         Pending
IP:             10.48.8.9
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/myapp-7cf96cf48
Containers:
  myapp:
    Container ID:
    Image:          mynginx
    Image ID:
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-8p622 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          False
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  default-token-8p622:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-8p622
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age              From                                                        Message
  ----     ------                 ----             ----                                                        -------
  Normal   Scheduled              4m               default-scheduler                                           Successfully assigned myapp-7cf96cf48-vsqb5 to gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-c7d671ed-br8j
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  4m               kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-c7d671ed-br8j  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-8p622"
  Normal   Pulling                2m (x4 over 4m)  kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-c7d671ed-br8j  pulling image "mynginx"
  Warning  Failed                 2m (x4 over 4m)  kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-c7d671ed-br8j  Failed to pull image "mynginx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: repository mynginx not found: does not exist or no pull access
  Warning  Failed                 2m (x4 over 4m)  kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-c7d671ed-br8j  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff                2m (x6 over 4m)  kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-c7d671ed-br8j  Back-off pulling image "mynginx"
  Warning  Failed                 2m (x6 over 4m)  kubelet, gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-c7d671ed-br8j  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Comment: where is this image `myapp`?

Comment: I just created that image in my cluster master node using docker build command. And when I execute docker images command, I can see it listed and I believe it is in my local registry?

Comment: run a 'kubectl get pods'  'kubectl describe pod <pod-id>' and give the output

Comment: to clarify, the image you want to use exists in a private repo? GKE will pull natively from GCR, for other private repositories, you will need to configure the [nodes to Authenticate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/)

Comment: With the describe output, I can see that it is pulling `mynginx` image, while at starting you mentioned you have made image in the name of `myapp`. So You have given wrong image tag while starting the deployment. Kindly check if you have given same image tag which is present on your local machine.

Comment: so my question is without pushing the image to docker hub or GCR, is it possible to deploy it using kubectl? Because this approach worked with minikube in Katakoda but its not working in GKE in GCP :(

Comment: Yes it is possible with GKE as well. If you have image present on local machine(check using `docker images`) and you define `imagePullPolicy` as `IfNotPresent`, it will work. The reason it is failing because you haven't provided the right image name in GKE. You provided `mynginx` as image name to your deployment while you have image name as `myapp`

Comment: No, that was my mistake in my 2nd post. I later modified myapp to mynginx. Sorry about that. But I again tried to deploy by making everything as mynginx. And still it is same.. Failed to pull image "mynginx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: repository mynginx not found: does not exist or no pull access

Comment: Could you please run `docker images` command on your node and paste output

Comment: xxx@gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-1fa56e6c-xzp8:~$ docker images
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.27/images/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186423/discussion-between-prafull-ladha-and-a-a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is your pod is going on the worker node and worker node doesn't have `mynginx` image present.

You need to copy the mynginx image from master node to worker node as follows:

Run following command on master node:

```
docker save -o <path for generated tar file> mynginx
```

Now copy the generated tar file to the worker node and load that image using following command:

```
docker load -i <path to image tar file>
```

This will load the `mynginx` image on your worker node and it will resolve your issue